# Execute a JavaScript function using image onclick

Tags: javascript

I'm attempting to execute the following JavaScript function(pop up a new window) when clicking on an image but doesn't work. can you please help me correct the code?

```
    <script language="javascript">
    var win = null;
    function NewWindow(wizpage, wizname, w, h, scroll){
    LeftPosition = (screen.width) ? (screen.width-w)/2 : 0;
    TopPosition = (screen.height) ? (screen.height-h)/2 : 0;
     settings = 'height=' + h + ',width=' + w + ',top= 100,' + TopPosition + 
   ',left=' + LeftPosition + ',scrollbars=' + scroll + ',resizable'
    win = window.open(wizpage, wizname, settings)
    }
    </script>
    <FORM>
    <INPUT TYPE="Image" SRC="https://communities-
    qa.connect.te.com/sites/GP/Indirect/PublishingImages/clickhere2.jpg" 
    Alt="Contact Us" onClick="
    NewWindow('www.google.com','name','590','390','yes');return false"></FORM>
```

thanks a lot

Comment: Are you using Chrome's DevTools or anything to find javascript errors? My guess looking at it is that its complaining about you trying to treat string like numbers. Use 590 and 390 instead of '590' and '390'

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.   Your code appears to work just fine -- you need to include the "http(s)://" in your url, is the only problem I can see.   Next time, please actually describe the problem you're having; "it doesn't work" is not enough information. This might be worth reading: [ask]

Answer (score -1):

Blocked opening 'https://www.google.com/' in a new window because the request was made in a sandboxed frame whose 'allow-popups' permission is not set.

```js
    var win = null;
    function NewWindow(wizpage, wizname, w, h, scroll){
    LeftPosition = (screen.width) ? (screen.width-w)/2 : 0;
    TopPosition = (screen.height) ? (screen.height-h)/2 : 0;
     settings = 'height=' + h + ',width=' + w + ',top= 100,' + TopPosition + 
   ',left=' + LeftPosition + ',scrollbars=' + scroll + ',resizable'
    win = window.open(wizpage, wizname, settings)
    }
```

```html
    <FORM>
    <INPUT TYPE="Image" SRC="https://communities-
    qa.connect.te.com/sites/GP/Indirect/PublishingImages/clickhere2.jpg" 
    Alt="Contact Us" onClick="
    NewWindow('https://www.google.com','name','590','390','yes');return false"></FORM>
```

Comment: That error message is because Stack Overflow's code snippet tool blocks popup windows, it's not related to the code itself (which is presumably not intended to be running in a sandboxed iframe.)

Comment: Code is useful locally

Comment: Thanks for your help. it works for me now but i have one more question, what I can do to execute the code without using the "<form>" tag?  the reason i'm asking is that, i need to embed the code to a SharePoint page, and the <form> tag is not supported in some cases.

Comment: Removal of the <form> tag can also be performed